# SQL Server Management Studio 2014 - unless I use the "Run as Administrator", no able to connect to local DB

Tags: ssms

I am using SSMS 2014, unless I launch ssms as Run as Administrator, I am not able to connect to my local db. It does not give any error message, It just keeps loading in the login screen for ever.

If I run the SSMS as Run as Administrator, It is working fine. PLEASE Help me resolve this issue

Comment: what are the permissions set on the localdb files? on your user directory?

Comment: Its public and sysadmin....  Even if I try to login with system administrator account also it is not logging in to the SSMS. When i click connect button it does not connect at all unless I run SSMS as a system administrator